# Delete rows from a text file with php

Tags: php

I have a text file as follows

```
href='https://www.example.com/tv/xxxxxxxx/playlist.m3u8'>TV 1
href='https://www.example.com/tv/xxxxxxxx/playlist.m3u8'>TV 2
href='https://www.example.com/tv/xxxxxxxx/playlist.m3u8'>TV 3
href='https://www.example.com/tv/xxxxxxxx/playlist.m3u8'>TV 4
href='https://www.example.com/tv/xxxxxxxx/playlist.m3u8'>TV 5
href='https://www.example.com/playlist/xxxxxxxx/playvod/vybz9h.mp4'>Film 1
href='https://www.example.com/playlist/xxxxxxxx/playvod/tq5mzt.mp4'>Film 2
href='https://www.example.com/playlist/xxxxxxxx/playvod/xegtnw.mp4'>Film 3
href='https://www.example.com/playlist/xxxxxxxx/playvod/16c9os.mp4'>Film 4
href='https://www.example.com/playlist/xxxxxxxx/playvod/r25dwc.mp4'>Film 5
```

being a very long text file, I'd like to eliminate the only lines of M3U8 connections and maintain only those with links to the films.
It's possible to do it?

Comment: A simple web search of *"php delete rows in file"* answers your question. Basic research is expected before asking. Come back when you have specific code problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lines = file("filename");

$result = "";

foreach($lines as $line){                                                                                                                                                                 

    if(strpos($line, "M3U8")){                                                                                                                                                                   
        $line = "";                                                                                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                                                                                         

    $result .= $line;                                                                                                                                                                         
}

file_put_contents("filename", $result);
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Perfect, thank you, it works perfectly

Comment: pleasure helping ya. :)